# Convert SQL server Query to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

Below mentioned query is in SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p 
INNER JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
INNER JOIN Users u ON p.UserId = u.UserId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON p.TagId = t.TagId 
INNER JOIN Locations l ON p.LocationId = l.LocationId 
left JOIN PostImages pm ON p.PostId = pm.PostId
WHERE p.CategoryId = 1 and **pm.PostimageId = (select top 1 postimageid from PostImages where PostImages.PostId=p.postid)**
```

Now I want to convert the above SQL query into LINQ

My LINQ query:

```
   var objPosts = (from p in _dbcontext.Posts
                            join us in _dbcontext.Users on p.UserId equals us.UserId
                            join tag in _dbcontext.Tags on p.TagId equals tag.TagId
                            join cat in _dbcontext.Categories on p.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
                            join loc in _dbcontext.Locations on p.LocationId equals loc.LocationId
                            join img in _dbcontext.PostImages on p.PostId equals img.PostId into gj
                            from postimg in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            where p.Disabled == false && p.CategoryId == userPost.CategoryId || p.UserId == userPost.UserId || p.TagId == userPost.TagId || p.LocationId == userPost.LocationId 
                            && postimg.PostImageId == (from pm in _dbcontext.PostImages where pm.PostImageId == p.PostId)


                            orderby p.PostId descending

                            select new
                            {
                                PostId = p.PostId,
                                PostTitle = p.Title,
                                //ImageInfo = postimg.ImagePath,
                                //ThumbNailInfo = p.ThubNailInfo,
                                PostShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,
                                UserId = us.UserId,
                                UserName = us.Name,
                                TagId = tag.TagId,
                                TagTitle = tag.TagTitle,
                                CategoryId = cat.CategoryId,
                                CategoryName = cat.CategoryName,
                                LocationId = loc.LocationId,
                                LocationName = loc.LocationName
                            });
```

I am almost done but I am unable to convert the mentioned SQL query into LINQ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are just missing the `First()` call for the inner query (corresponding to the `top 1` part of the SQL query):

```
&& postimg.PostImageId == (from pm in _dbcontext.PostImages where pm.PostId == p.PostId select pm.PostImageId).First()
```

Comment: It gives me error: A query body must end with a select clause or a group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Please use FirstOrDefault like here :

```
&& postimg.PostImageId == (from pm in _dbcontext.PostImages where pm.PostImageId == p.PostId).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its not relevant answer but it should definitely work. Have you heard about [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/). If not give it a try.